# ROS network of processes

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On the ROS Introduction page it says ... The ROS runtime "graph" is a peer-to-peer network of processes (potentially distributed across machines) that are loosely coupled using the ROS communication infrastructure ...
For the processes to be distributed across machines do they all have to be running ROS on top of Linux or can only run Linux without the need to install ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188693/ros-network-of-processes/) by [vreg](https://answers.ros.org/users/19867/vreg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-08-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to run ROS nodes on multiple machines, ROS must be installed on every machine.

Further, each node must be installed on the machine you want to run it on. The ROS launch infrastructure does not do any code distribution for you.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1